# How do I filter POST requests with Postman Interceptor?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am using the [Postman Interceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo) Chrome extension to capture every request I make through Chrome. However, I am only interested in viewing sent POST requests.

Is there a Regex filter I can use to ignore GET requests and only display POST requests?

[image: Intercepted requests from Postman Interceptor]

Answer (score 0):

Add filter and then define the method you need
[image]